# Invoking Commands from ListView in MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, custom-controls, winrt-xaml, prism

I'm using Prism for Windows Runtime to wire up events in my Views with DelegateCommands in my ViewModels. I am wondering what would be the best way to invoke commands (e.g. select item) from a ListView that contains Buttons (or custom controls derived freom the Button class). I'd like to keep the effects (e.g. background change, tilt effect) provided by the Button control. But the button unfortunately absorbs the click events, which, in consequence, I cannot use in the ListView to hook up my commands e.g with the following XAML (and Behaviors SDK):

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableItemsList}" SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <customControls:NavMenuButton Style="{StaticResource SelectionListMenuButton}" Content="{Binding Nickname}" DescriptionText="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ItemSelectedCommand}" />
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ListView>
```

What would be the best way to achieve this? I have found similar questions, but the difference here is that the controls in the list items are apparently "stealing" the click event (while it works just fine with e.g. a simple TextBlock).

Comment: why not bind to SelectedItem instead of using eventrtrigger stuff?

Comment: hummm do you want to call methode in your viewmodel from your button inside your listview? If it is, you just need to use the listviewdatacontext and call your command like this. Command="{Binding DataContext.YourCommand,elementName=yourListView}

Comment: @blindmeis: You mean on SelectionChanged? My understanding is that it does not implement ICommand, so I would need to add some logic in the code behind of the view. Not a real problem but somehow breaking the pattern. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: @MatDev8: Hey, this works - great! Could you post it as an answer so I can click the check mark? For completeness perhaps add CommandParameter="{Binding Name}" to pass the selected item as a parameter to the command. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To close this question, here is the solution based on MatDev8's comment above (thank you!):

```
<ListView x:Name="myListView" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableItemsList}" SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <customControls:CustomTextButton Style="{StaticResource SelectionListMenuButton}" 
                                             Content="{Binding Nickname}" 
                                             DescriptionText="{Binding Name}"
                                             Command="{Binding DataContext.ItemSelectedCommand, ElementName=myListView}"
                                             CommandParameter="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

To have the commands binding in ListView you can use buttons within the ListView.

now for the clicking related issue you can modify your button's Controltemplate to make it look like a simple textblock. this way your clicking will also work on the listview and it will not be displayed as button.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
    </ControlTemplate>
```

You can also customize the click event in other way like moving focus to the button should also raise your click event(indirectly fire your command). This will help in your case of Listview where just moving to next item should also fire the command.

Comment: Thank you. I think I need to ask to understand. My control template looks a bit like you suggested - a bit more complex. It adds a second line and it contains the VisualStateManager. Simplifying it removes the effects but the button still grabs the click event away from the ListView. That I can prevent by setting the button's IsEnabled property to False, in which case I also lose the effects but then it works.

In the second part of your answer, you mean invoking the command in code behind? I considered that but was hoping for a way to bind the command directly in XAML.